# prevent right click on adsense areas

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have the following domain: holanda-today.nl

in this domain I prevent user to perform right click and it's working fine, 
but the problem when I added google adsense the user can perform right click just above ads areas, I tried to find out what is the problem, I discovered that the google added new html document for each ads area then added the ads inside it.

how can I force javascript function apply in all html documents.

I used the following code to prevent right click:
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());

please help.

thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why do you want to annoy users?

Comment: This is a policy. friend :)

Comment: Beyond the fact that this is mightily annoying and usually completely useless, you want want to read the Adsense Terms and conditions about changing anything related to their ads...